# prestoSQL aggregate columns and rows into one column

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to aggregate some columns and rows into one column in prestoSQL table.

```
with example_table as (
      select * from (
             values ('A', 'nh', 7), ('A', 'mn', 4), ('A', 'sv', 3),
                    ('B', 'tb', 6), ('B', 'ty', 5), ('A', 'rw', 2),
                    ('C', 'op', 9), ('C', 'au', 8)
               ) example_table("id", "time", "value")
       )
    
select id, agg(value, time) # Unexpected parameters (integer, VARCHAR(2)) for function array_agg. Expected: array_agg(T) T
from example_table
group by id
```

I would like to combine column "time" and "value" as one column and then aggregate all rows by "id" such that

```
id.  time_value_agg
A.   [['nh', 7], ['mn', 4], ['sv', 3], ['rw', 2]
B.   [['tb', 6], ['tv',5]
C.   [['op', 9], ['au', 8]]
```

the column

```
time_value_agg
```

should be an array of str. If the "time" col is not str, cast it to str.

I am not sure which function can be used for this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`array_agg` can be applied to single column only. If times are unique per id you can turn data into map:

```sql
select id, map(array_agg(time), array_agg(value)) time_value_agg
from example_table
group by id
```

Output:

| id | time_value_agg |
| --- | --- |
| C | {op=9, au=8} |
| A | {mn=4, sv=3, rw=2, nh=7} |
| B | {ty=5, tb=6} |

Or turn data into `ROW` type (or map) before aggregation:

```sql
select id,
    array_agg(arr) time_value_agg
from (
        select id, cast (row(time, value) as row(time varchar, value integer))arr
        from example_table
    )
group by id
```

Output:

| id | time_value_agg |
| --- | --- |
| C | [{time=op, value=9}, {time=au, value=8}] |
| A | [{time=nh, value=7}, {time=mn, value=4}, {time=sv, value=3}, {time=rw, value=2}] |
| B | [{time=tb, value=6}, {time=ty, value=5}] |